# C - check if this program is already running

Tags: c, unix, process

Is there a way to check, if a program is itself already running? I have only found answers for MS windows; is there a platform-independent/*nix way to do so?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your solution for Microsoft Windows? Was it a [named mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I don't remember; I was just searching for a way to do it, and all the search results were for Windows. I found several different solutions to it, but they don't matter to me since I don't program for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX, you can use [named semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for this purpose.

Whenever the program starts, it should use the function [`sem_open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) to open a semaphore with a unique name that is hard-coded into the program, creating the semaphore if it does not already exist, and then use [`sem_trywait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) to attempt to acquire the semaphore. The initial value of the semaphore should be 1. If acquiring the semaphore fails due to the semaphore already having been acquired, then the program can probably assume that another instance of the same program is already running.

Comment: I personally prefer binding to a Unix-domain socket with a (hopefully) unique pathname over using a named semaphore.  It's simpler.  Cleanup after an abnormal termination is about the same.  Binding to a standard TCP port is even simpler - if your process terminates abnormally it's cleaned up automatically.  But binding to an actual TCP port is a bit more likely to have additional impacts.